# Flow: preserving type during map/filter/reduce

Tags: ecmascript-6, flowtype

How can filter/reduce typed objects while correctly inferring the types of keys? For example:

```
/* @flow */
type A = {
  a0?: string,
  a1?: boolean,
  a2?: number
}
type B = {
  b0?: string,
  b1?: boolean,
  b2?: number
}
type AB = A & B

const keysA = ['a0', 'a1', 'a2']

// Given an AB object, keep only the keys that belong in type A
function keepA(ab: AB):A {
  return keysA
    .filter(prop => ab.hasOwnProperty(prop))
    .reduce((obj, prop) => {
      obj[prop] = ab[prop]
      return obj
    }, {} )
}

function flowTest(ab: AB) {
  const a = keepA(ab)
  return a
}
```

This raises an error:

```
obj[prop] = ab[prop]                     
            ^ Cannot return `keysA.filter(...).reduce(...)` 
              because boolean [1] is incompatible with 
              string [2] in property `a0`.
References:
4:   a1?: boolean,
          ^ [1]
3:   a0?: string,
          ^ [2]
```

It seems like in the assignment `obj[prop] = ab[prop]`, flow thinks the right-hand-side could be any of `string | boolean | number`.

Here it is on flow.org/try:

https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoALgTwA4FMwCCYAvGAN6phgCGADAPwBcYAzugE4CWAdgOYA0lGgEYmYAEZw4MXNW6Cq1AExjuAVwC243O1QBfDDnwAhEuSHiGzNlz4KJo5pOmz5Flc3Vad+w3kKmpEQAZGDGqKgAxnDcbGAA1riYLESkANoA5HQZ-GBZwjl5yhkAuhHAwGAA4pwAbrjcNI0EpnDiAFa4kei5ibjYYDEwmGDoABb4icmjY9ToErjwfGA8o0aEqFBq3N2cMQm4-QQAFNTizC0AlIxEFFTsuOhq7I1TKUJUAHRQnDDoOsdsOw4ANiAA+GjiT6zFgAeQQ3AACsC8OwsICUZdLh8wJ8HgATNSRXDHY5tdq5IEgy4kCF3KgM8lpKnYEpmM7MlFlBkMh5PF6DDo4vS5Mh6MDYgybba7fawRAAFVwbFO5wCNPp0Vi82oZj62BOZ2x90ez0a1F8QA

I am pretty new to Flow (and type-checking in general).

Comment: `.filter(prop => ab[prop] )` is probably not what you meant to say. The closure that you give to `filter` is supposed to return a `boolean`, but this will return a `string`, `boolean` or `number`, depending on which property you access.

Comment: Flow will not be able to deduce that the values from the `keysA` array are exactly the field names from `A`.  Even if it could, some other code could modify the `keysA` array and then it would break - Flow runs statically and couldn't know if that would happen or not.

Comment: @PeterHall Thanks for pointing out the filter bug. That was foolish—I changed it to `ab.hasOwnProperty(prop)`. Re "Flow will not be able to deduce...", can you suggest a reasonable way to refactor this that Flow would understand?

Comment: Something like: https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoALgTwA4FMwCCYAvGAN4A+qYYAhgAwD8AXGAM7oBOAlgHYDmAGmp0AjCzAAjOHBi5avYTVoAmVo14BXALaTcnVBQC+GHPgBCJclRqSmrDjwFKp41tNnzFIySolbdfUMTLDxCS1IiADIwc1RUKE1eAGN0bjheMABrXFxsAgAKWklWAnMASlLyEU5cdE1OTLI6elZigDoGQTE2yU7RbtVezpUwEyMgA

Comment: @PeterHall That will include optional properties of `ab` as ownProperties of `keepA(ab)` (with value `undefined`). A `for...in` loop over `ab` seems to work: [flow.org/try](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoALgTwA4FMwCCYAvGAN6phgCGADAPwBcYAzugE4CWAdgOYA0lGgEYmYAEZw4MXNW6Cq1AExjuAVwC243O1QBfDDnwAhEuSHiGzNlz4KJo5pOmz5Flc3Vad+w3kKmpEQAZGDGqKgAxnDcbGAA1riYLESkANoA5HQZ-GBZwjl5yhkAuhHAwGAA4pwAbrjcNI0EpnDiAFa4kei5ibjYYDEwmGDoABb4icmjY9ToErjwfGA8o0aEqFBq3N2cMQm4-QQAFNTizC0AlBfmVNGx8+i4GgOkZGAGVFBw7GDH93EpitGmdLrcqCsoH8pikAHQ8SIwNQAE1wLGOU0uYIoEIhTxeaSmJTMZ0JSTKuM+HyE7Fw6DU7Ea+OwviAA)